# How to change SVN authentication details in AnkhSVN in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I want to change the username and password for SVN in Visual Studio 2010 AnkhSVN plugin. How can i do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found it. To clear the cached username/passwords you can go to:

`Tools` > `Options` > `Source Control` > `Subversion Environment` > `Authentication Cache`

Comment: Can there be separate Authentication Logins for separate projects? I want to use different login for a project in VS 2010, and separate login for a project in VS 2012.

Answer (score 5):

For **Tortoise Svn** :

Right Click @ anywhere in the Window

Go to TORTOISE SVN > SETTINGS > SAVED DATA

and Click clear for authentication Data.

Answer (score 0):

And After clear your Authentification Data, to add an other user

Right click in your folder:
Go to > SVN Update

It will prompt you to enter the user credentials.
And enter your user credentials and click on Save authentication checkbox.

Now, you received SVN updated with the provided user credentials.